# Perl Invalid conversion in printf

Tags: perl, printf

I have an error code:

```
Invalid conversion in printf: "%A"' printing %A characters in a URL
```

Here is my code:

```
$url =~ s/\%([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})/pack('C', hex($1))/seg;
printf "%-10s $url\n", $res_request{$key};
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you very much,
AL

Answer (score 11):

Instead of putting `$url` in the format string, use an `%s` format:

```
printf "%-10s %s\n", $res_request{$key}, $url;
```

(You should never interpolate variables into the format string that have parts that may be mistaken for formatting codes.)